# mysql_affected_rows is not giving desired result in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach($chk as $key=>$invoiceno)
{
  $QryUp = mysql_query("update `tbl1` set `paid` = 'y' where `invoice_no`='".$invoiceno."' and `uniquekey`='".$_SESSION['uniquekey']."'") or die(mysql_error());
  $id=mysql_affected_rows();

 //insert data into tbl_school_account
 $QryIns=mysql_query("insert into `tbl2` (`type`, `ref_id`) values('d', '$id')");
}
```

here `$id` return same value.
exa:when this loop is work it update `tbl1` table.their id is 1 and 2.it update perfect. but `mysql_affected_rows` return only 1 (two time).

so where's the problem?

and i am aware about **deprecated function**.

Comment: I think the Database values for the respective tables should be already "y". Therefore, no values are updating and hence, mysql_affected_rows() does not return 1.

Comment: there are also other fields in tables.and update is work fine,all the values are updated.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_affected_rows` call returns the *number* of affected rows, not the PK of affected rows. You're going to have to run a `SELECT` using the invoice ID etc to get the information that you appear to want.

Comment: means it is not similar as `mysql_insert_id`?

Comment: No. It returns how many rows were modified by the previous query. If you want which ones were edited, you have to SELECT on the same criteria you used in the UPDATE.

Comment: ok..i understod but here query update the two rows then why it return only one?

Comment: Ah, I misjudged. Does it update two rows at the same time or across seperate queries?

Comment: @DS9 Well...yeah. `mysql_affected_rows` returns the number of rows that the previous query affected.

Answer (score 1):

You want this function instead of affected_rows:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

"Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT)."

Comment: From the MySQL manual, the mysql_insert_id is only updated on an `INSERT`, or when `INSERT` or `UPDATE` is used to set a column value with `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`.

Comment: Oh i missed that, in that case i think slugonamission is right and you are going to have to look them up yourself.